# Does a nested table retain order while not being stored?

Tags: oracle, plsql, nested-table

I have a PLSQL function that populates and returns a nested table:

```
select distinct id bulk collect into my_nested_table
from user
order by id;
return my_nested_table;
```

According to the docs nested tables are multisets and have no inherent ordering.

Can I nevertheless assume that the nested table returned from the function above will be ordered by id(as the `select` statement implies) and retain that order as long as I don't store it in the DB?

Providing a link to documentation is a plus. :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First of all you should know, what is `NESTED TABLE`

According to [Oracle Doc](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B10501_01/appdev.920/a96624/05_colls.htm)

> Within the database, nested tables can be considered **one-column
>   database tables**. Oracle stores the rows of a nested table in **no
>   particular order**. But, when you retrieve the nested table into a
>   PL/SQL variable, the rows are given consecutive subscripts starting at
>   1. That gives you array-like access to individual rows

It's **one-column table**, which has behaviour of `array`, but they are unbounded (size can increase dynamically). Moreover, initially `NESTED TABLE` are dense in nature but later they became sparse (once you remove any element from it).

[image]

Comment: Can I assume that the `bulk collect into` statement will insert into the nested table at consecutive subscripts starting at 1?

Comment: yes. That is what happened. It will start the subscript from 1. If it was not initialized

Comment: <nitpick>When filling a collection with BULK COLLECT, indices will always start at 1, and the collection will always be dense - regardless of whether it was initialized before or not</nitpick>

Answer (score 0):

you can relies on order of collection until it holds in pl/sql and does not perform any add or delete element further to collection.